# How to access this API without the use of Jquery or AJAX?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking to get data from the http://dev.markitondemand.com/ API. The API was designed to be used with AJAX calls, but for technical reasons I cannot include JQuery in my project. How do I get the info that [this page](http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myFunction) provides without making an AJAX call to the server? JSON and XML are both fine.

Comment: That's not even designed for "ajax". That's a JSONP API (your "this page" link). Google JSONP. Basically you define a function called myFunction then include their URL as a script, which will call your function with their data. no "ajax or jquery" required

Comment: Why do you refuse to use AJAX? Why not use AJAX without jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

An ajax call is simply an XMLHttpRequest that can be used to fetch data in various formats (like JSON and XML) from a server. Jquery has some functions which simplify the process of making ajax calls, but it is not needed.

You can just use the [built-in XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) API to make the request using vanilla javascript.

Example

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Lookup', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is a way to fetch data from a server. Using jQuery is not the only way to perform AJAX. You can do it AJAX requests with VanillaJS (pure JavaScript). To do this :

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
   var xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Lookup', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

> See [this MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for a better understanding of AJAX.
>
> See [this W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) tutorial to know how to handle Internet Explorer.